# Cannot create new EJB on Eclipse EE

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb

Look Below. How am I able to install EJB? I am using Java EE isn't it installed EJB by default?? I have screen shot the problem below

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: An EJB is just a POJO that has been annotated with `@Stateless` or `@Stateful`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: EJB used for web development is it not? if it has only few functionality why it is standard?

Comment: EJBs are part of the Java EE platform and can be used as the back end for a web based application. EJBs are very powerful and can be configured to do a lot of things depending upon your requirements. The `@Stateless` and `@Stateful` annotations are simply used by the EJB container to determine which beans it needs to manage. Again, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To learn EJB by doing practicals. But I can't do them without creating it in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special in Eclipse to create an EJB project, as from Eclipse's perspective an EJB is just a bunch of Java classes (POJO's) which get compiled into either a JAR file or a WAR file. It's what the you're Java EE Application Server does with the EJB that makes it special.

The EJB container which is part of the Java EE Application Server will scan the compiled Java classes and look for classes that have been annotated with either `@Stateless` or `@Stateful`; these classes will become EJBs. You can then inject the EJB into another class by annotating a field with `@EJB`.

As an example you can create an EJB called `HelloWorldService` using the following code:

```
@Stateless
public class HelloWorldService {

    public String sayHello() {
        String helloMessage = "Hello World";
        return helloMessage;
    }
}
```

You can then inject the `HelloWorldServiceEJB` into another class using the following code:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    @EJB
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldService;

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(helloWorldService.sayHello());
    }
}
```

This is an oversimplified example and in reality you would never use an EJB for something this simple, but nevertheless it demonstrates the basics of creating an EJB and injecting it into another class.

I'd suggest looking for some tutorials on using EJBs or finding a book on the subject as the example I've given you was just to show that you don't need to do anything special in Eclipse.

Hope this helps.